# Как найти все вхождения подстроки во фразу, за не более N-циклов?

Tags: java, c#, c++, строки

> Дана фраза
>
> > (алгоритм - набор инструкций, описывающих порядок действий исполнителя для достижения результата решения задачи по конечное число действий, система правил выполнения дискретного процесса, достигает поставленной цели за конечное время. Для визуализации алгоритмов часто используют блок-схемы)
>
> и подстрока `(алгоритм)`.
>
> Найти все вхождения подстроки в фразу, если таковых нет, выдать сообщение. Программа должна выполнять не более `N-циклов`. Где `N` - необходимо ввести.
>
> Возможна реализация на С#, С++, Java.

Я начал делать на C#.

Код:

```
    string s1 = "алгоритм – алгоритм набір інструкцій, які описують порядок дій виконавця, щоб досягти результату розв'язання задачі за скінченну кількість дій; система правил виконання дискретного процесу, яка досягає поставленої мети за скінченний час. Для візуалізації алгоритмів часто використовують блок-схеми";
    string s2 = "алгоритм";

    Console.Write("Выполнить не больше: " );
    int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int i = 0;  
    int x = -1; 
    N = -1;
    while (i != -1)
    {
        i = s1.IndexOf(s2, x + 1);
        x = i; 
        N++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Количество вхождений слова алгоритм: " + N);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Не могу понять, как ограничить количество нахождений, чтобы выполнилось не более N- заданных повторений.

Comment: Введем N=1. Ну и как вы намерены найти все подстроки в строке без циклов вовсе? (Конечно, кроме как - зная заранее строку и подстроку, просто вывести позиции вручную найденных подстрок :)).

Comment: Извините, но в задании написан бред про N введённое с клавиатуры и не имеющее никакой связи с длиной введённой строки. Вероятно подразумевается, что из _уже найденных_ образцов нужно вывести не более N, где N вводится с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s1 = "алгоритм – алгоритм набір інструкцій, які описують порядок дій виконавця, щоб досягти результату розв'язання задачі за скінченну кількість дій; система правил виконання дискретного процесу, яка досягає поставленої мети за скінченний час. Для візуалізації алгоритмів часто використовують блок-схеми";
string s2 = "алгоритм";

Console.Write("Выполнить не больше: ");
int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int iterationsCount = -1;
int nextIndex = -999; 
while (nextIndex != -1 && iterationsCount < N) {
    nextIndex = s1.IndexOf(s2, nextIndex == -999 ? 0 : nextIndex + 1); 
    iterationsCount++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Количество вхождений слова `" + s2 + "`: " + iterationsCount);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: по моему можно обойтись и 3 интами.  x=s1.IndexOf(s2, x + 1)

Comment: Тогда изначально X должен быть равен -1 чтобы поиск был с нуля. А в while проверка на X != -1. В таком случае цикл бы не выполнился. Решил вопрос немного иначе.

Comment: ну тут явно задача учебного уровня, так что не особо важно) По факту количество вхождений в строку можно найти более изящными методами :)
что то вроде int count = (s1.Length - s1.Replace(s2, "").Length) / s2.Length;

Comment: Или вовсе регулярным выражением

Comment: нет нет, думаю, что я предложил не создаст класс регулярки и будет очень даже "невесомый". Придумал не я, такой способ часто используется для нахождения количества слов в string, ну и количество подстрок

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь регулярным выражением, очень легко определить вхождения:

```
public class Application {

    private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?ui)(алгоритм)");
    private static final String TEXT = "алгоритм – алгоритм набір інструкцій, які описують порядок дій виконавця, "
            + "щоб досягти результату розв'язання задачі за скінченну кількість дій; "
            + "система правил виконання дискретного процесу, яка досягає поставленої мети за скінченний час. "
            + "Для візуалізації алгоритмів часто використовують блок-схеми.";
    private static final int number = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher matcher = REGEX.matcher(TEXT);
        int count = 0;
        while (count != number && matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```